# R: Changing diagonal of sparse matrix is very slow

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I hava a sparse matrix with zeros on the main diagonal that I want to change to ones, but compared to a QR-decomposition the operation is very very slow:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),ncol=3)
mat1 <- Matrix::bdiag(mat,mat,mat)
mat2 <- Matrix::bdiag(mat,mat,mat)
identity_mat <- Matrix::Diagonal(9)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  qr(mat1),
  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1,
  mat1 + identity_mat
)
```

results in

```
Unit: microseconds
                    expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
                qr(mat1)   55.825   69.0080   79.16561   72.9365   85.6095  149.676   100
 Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1  302.172  326.2365  379.60509  364.1985  401.8005  756.477   100
     mat1 + identity_mat 1714.578 1762.8665 2006.50270 1974.4125 2073.1795 6671.644   100
```

How can I set the diagonal to ones faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `RcppArmadillo`:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(code="
arma::sp_mat set_unit_diagonal(arma::sp_mat& A) {
      A.diag().ones();
    return A;
}", depends="RcppArmadillo")

mat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),ncol=3)
mat1 <- Matrix::bdiag(mat,mat,mat)
mat2 <- Matrix::bdiag(mat,mat,mat)
mat3 <- Matrix::bdiag(mat,mat,mat)
identity_mat <- Matrix::Diagonal(9)
```

The solution is very quick:

```
Unit: microseconds
                    expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval
                qr(mat1)   52.374   62.4805   69.12798   65.747   75.4455   110.630   100
 Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1  272.026  289.9080  323.98992  300.557  358.5355   419.486   100
     mat1 + identity_mat 1543.191 1620.2835 1913.68513 1637.990 1970.8930 13572.716   100
 set_unit_diagonal(mat3)    7.426   11.9100   14.00686   13.970   15.5955    26.484   100
```

Comment: This is fast for small matrices, but if you try it on a large matrix it won't be as fast as changing the object in R directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly faster (it uses the triplet sparse matrix instead of the compressed one).

```
N <- 3
mat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),ncol=3)
mat1 <- do.call(Matrix::bdiag, replicate(N, mat, simplify = FALSE))
mat2 <- do.call(Matrix::bdiag, replicate(N, mat, simplify = FALSE))
mat3 <- Matrix::.bdiag(replicate(N, mat, simplify = FALSE))
identity_mat <- Matrix::Diagonal(3*N)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  qr(mat1),
  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1,
  Matrix::diag(mat3) <- 1,
  mat1 + identity_mat
)

#> Unit: microseconds
#>                     expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#>                 qr(mat1)   50.519   65.8000   83.40258   74.1075   84.9095   451.866   100
#>  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1  266.200  318.6375  452.58706  338.8715  405.3270  5460.654   100
#>  Matrix::diag(mat3) <- 1  164.340  181.7700  246.14324  204.1055  235.4700  3083.771   100
#>      mat1 + identity_mat 1519.636 1739.8940 2297.10306 1863.0430 2251.7720 18617.782   100
```

For much larger matrices these barely take any time longer (below is for for `N = 300`) which makes me wonder if it's just making the S4 objects that is slow (There's probably lots of validation going on in the background).

```
N <- 300

#> Unit: microseconds
#>                     expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
#>                 qr(mat1) 239799.888 251484.867 260169.1626 257957.9940 265350.8880 321234.482   100
#>  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1    396.399    415.131    529.8535    495.5805    575.4920   2367.596   100
#>  Matrix::diag(mat3) <- 1    257.128    276.636    361.8436    322.2445    380.6375   2210.064   100
#>      mat1 + identity_mat   1605.454   1692.756   2176.5367   1833.2210   2000.9815  16803.231   100
```

If you can make assumptions about your matrices you may be able to hack it to work faster. In particular if the matrix you are writing the diagonal to has no entries on the diagonal beforehand (as in your example) you could do this:

```
N <- 3
mat4 <- Matrix::.bdiag(replicate(N, mat, simplify = FALSE))
insert_diagonal <- function(m, d) {
  m@i <- c(m@i, 0:(d-1))
  m@j <- c(m@j, 0:(d-1))
  m@x <- c(m@x, rep(1, d))
  m
}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  qr(mat1),
  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1,
  Matrix::diag(mat3) <- 1,
  insert_diagonal(mat4, 3*N)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>                      qr(mat1)  63.885  81.0315  97.14267  90.4660  99.4635 413.534   100
#>       Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1 325.229 368.2320 417.94677 408.6095 425.9595 755.734   100
#>       Matrix::diag(mat3) <- 1 195.907 212.6790 266.83832 249.9585 266.0280 796.030   100
#>  insert_diagonal(mat4, 3 * N)  23.676  30.2365  35.59022  35.5075  39.2745  62.028   100
```

Comment: You are right that it's probably best to directly modify the sparse Matrix object. The standard format however is `dgCMatrix` (e.g. multiplying a `dgTMatrix` by a scalar gives a `dgCMarix`) and there it's not so trivial to efficiently set the main diagonal.

Comment: Yes, and then you have to worry about whether you are just moving the time consuming step somewhere else in your code if it is doing conversions behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
`diag<-`(as.matrix(mat1), 1)
```

and benchmark

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  qr(mat1),
  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1,
  `diag<-`(as.matrix(mat1), 1)
)
```

gives

```
Unit: microseconds
                         expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval
                     qr(mat1)  52.4  56.55  61.457  60.85  64.05 103.5   100
      Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1 269.2 275.35 290.202 282.75 297.65 443.4   100
 `diag<-`(as.matrix(mat1), 1)  38.6  42.40  47.721  46.10  48.90 147.4   100
```

---

**Update**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  qr(mat1),
  Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1,
  as(`diag<-`(as.matrix(mat1), 1), "sparseMatrix")
)
```

shows

```
Unit: microseconds
                                             expr   min     lq    mean median
                                         qr(mat1)  50.6  56.55  61.592   60.2
                          Matrix::diag(mat2) <- 1 270.6 277.20 290.993  280.3
 as(`diag<-`(as.matrix(mat1), 1), "sparseMatrix")  96.6 105.45 111.285  112.1
     uq   max neval
  64.00 179.5   100
 294.35 492.3   100
 115.25 136.2   100
```

Comment: This is not useful because it returns a dense matrix.

Comment: @FrederikZiebell I updated my answer, which is slower than the `Cpp` method, but faster than `diag(mat2)<-1`